# Some <protocol> causes exc_bad_access

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to use an opaque result type in an extension with a Self contraint. If used  on a static function it causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the function is called.

```swift
protocol IntValue {
    func getValue() -> Int
}

struct LeetValue: IntValue {
    func getValue() -> Int {
        1337
    }
}

extension IntValue where Self == LeetValue {
    static func leet() -> some IntValue {
        LeetValue()
    }
}

func printValue(_ value: IntValue) {
    print("value: \(value.getValue())")
}
```

```swift
// In another file

printValue(.leet()) // crash
```

I've searched around a little bit and found out multiple things:

- If the extension is in the same file as the `printValue(.leet())` it doesn't crash.
- If I change `static func leet() -> some IntValue` to a computed property (i.e: `static var leet: some IntValue`), calling `printValue(.leet)` doesn't crash either.

From my understanding of opaque result types, the type must be known at compile time, so I would expect the type to be actually resolved at compile time too and not throw a runtime error.

I know this can be solved by avoiding opaque result type in the extension, and returning `Self` or `LeetValue` solve the issue, but I'm trying to understand if I'm misusing opaque result type in this scenario (which would be strange considering that it works well with a static computed property, but not with a static function) or is it something else?

*I'm currently using Swift 5.7.2, I don't know if it behave the same on Swift 5.8.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Swift compiler bug. It still exists in 5.8. I recommend adding your slightly simpler case to [the existing bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/61357).